# why when we use chaining bind we get first context?

Tags: javascript, this

why when we use chaining bind we get first context (why not last)?

```js
function showName() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

let user = {
  name: "John",
};

let user2 = {
  name: "Den",
}

let binded = showName.bind(user).bind(user2);
binded(); // "John"
```

why chaining bind works like that?

Comment: Interesting. If you do `console.dir(binded)`, you can see that the `[[BindedThis]]` symbol's value is `"Den"` and not `"John"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function that has been "bound" with `bind` cannot be bound differently afterwards. This is because `bind` returns a *new* function that acts as a wrapper. But that wrapper function does not use its own `this` binding, so calling `bind` on *that* function will not change its ultimate behaviour.

It may help to look at an implementation of `bind`:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(boundThis, ...boundArgs) {
    return (...args) => this.call(boundThis, ...boundArgs, ...args);
}
```

As you can see, the *returned* function is a function that does not have `this` binding (it is an arrow function), and so calling `bind` on it will not influence the previous `this` behaviour.

You could also imagine it with a standard `function`:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(boundThis, ...boundArgs) {
    const that = this;
    return function (...args) {
        return that.call(boundThis, ...boundArgs, ...args);
    };
}
```

Again, you can see that although the returned function can be bound to a different `this`, it doesn't *use* `this` (but `that`), so the second `bind` will not influence the `this` binding of the original function.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

„A bound function can be further bound by calling boundFn.bind(thisArg, /* more args */), which creates another bound function boundFn2. The newly bound thisArg value is ignored, because the target function of boundFn2, which is boundFn, already has a bound this. When boundFn2 is called, it would call boundFn, which in turn calls fn. The arguments that fn ultimately receives are, in order: the arguments bound by boundFn, arguments bound by boundFn2, and the arguments received by boundFn2.”